# ¿Como cambio un texto de un textarea a otro textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

Este es el codigo que llevo por el momento lo que busco es intercambiar el texto del texto1 al texto 2 y viceversa

```
    <script>
        function Intercambiar(){
            var p1 = document.getElementById("Texto1").value;
            var p2 = document.getElementById("Texto2").value;
            Texto2.setValue(p1);
            Texto1.setValue(p2);
        }
    </script>
<body>
    <div>
        <textarea id="Texto1" class="inline-txtarea"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea id="Texto2" class="inline-txtarea"></textarea>
    </div>
        <input type="button" style="position: absolute;left: 10%;" value="Intercambiar" onclick="Intercambiar()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para cambiar el valor de un textarea harías esto:

```
document.getElementById ("Texto1").value = "Valor de ejemplo"
```

Y si quieres invertir los valores de ambos textareas lo harías así:

```
var Textarea1 = document.getElementById ("Texto1")
var Textarea2 = document.getElementById ("Texto2")
var Valor1 = Textarea1.value
Textarea1.value = Textarea2.value
Textarea2.value = Valor1
```

El valor de Textarea1 lo guardarías en una variable para no perderlo al asignarle a Textarea1 el valor de Textarea2. Puedes adaptar este código según tu estilo de programar. Espero sirva.